# If JComboBox is editable, how to cast the entered string to object?

Tags: java, casting, jframe, jcombobox

So I have this class "Member" :

```
package pkgData;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Member implements Comparable<Member>, Serializable{
  /**
  * 
  */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String name;
  private String city;

  public Member(String nameOfMember,String location) {
      super();
      this.name = nameOfMember;
      this.city=location;
  }


  public String getNameOfMember() {
      return name;
  }

  public String getLocationOfMember() {
      return city;
  }

  public void setNameOfMember(String nameOfMember) {
      this.name = nameOfMember;
  }


  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return name +", " + city;
  }


  @Override
  public int compareTo(Member o) {
      int result =this.getNameOfMember().compareTo(o.getNameOfMember());

      if(result==0){
          result = this.getLocationOfMember().compareTo(o.getLocationOfMember());
      }

      return result;
  }



}
```

And I have a JComboBox which is EDITABLE and the model of the ComboBox is DefaultComboBoxModel.

So the problem is that if I cast the selectedItem:

```
Member nameOfMember = (Member)memberModel.getSelectedItem();            
    if(nameOfMember== null)
        throw new Exception("please select a name and a location");
```

It only checks if the entered string is empty. If I enter a string like "Name, Location" I always get the exception that String cannot be cast to Member. Which String to I have to enter that the String can be cast to Member?

Here is my JComboBox:

```
private JComboBox<Member> getComboBoxMember() {
    if (comboBoxMember == null) {
        comboBoxMember = new JComboBox<Member>();
        comboBoxMember.setEditable(true);
        comboBoxMember.setModel(memberModel);
    }
    return comboBoxMember;
}
```

and here the global variables:

```
private DefaultComboBoxModel<Member> memberModel;
private JComboBox<Member> comboBoxMember;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
String nameOfMember = (String) memberModel
        .getSelectedItem();if(nameOfMember==null)throw new Exception("please select a name and a location");else

{
String[] parts = nameOfMember.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0]; // name
String part2 = parts[1]; // location
Member member=new Member(part1, part2);
}
```

Comment: but I want that if I select an MEMBER from the memberModel that I do not have to split it. Like selectedMem = (Member) memberModel.getSeletedItem(). In this case I have to split each time the string and cast it to the member. So I don't have to split every time, because I have already the Member

Answer (score 0):

**String split & cast method**

What you can do is first of all test if the string you get is null, or if it matches well you format. Then, you can create a new object with these elements.

Here's a small example code :

```
String memberData = (String)memberModel.getSelectedItem();
if(memberData == null || memberData.split(", ")[0].isEmpty() || memberData.split(", ")[1].isEmpty()) {
    throw new Exception("Data is incorrect, please provide name and location separated with ", ");
}
Member member = new Member(memberData.split(", ")[0], memberData.split(", ")[1]);
```

---

**JComboBox method**

With Java 7 happened a new possibility of extension to `JComboBox`, which can now be generically parameterized (as for `ArrayList`s) in the form `JComboBox<Type>`. Thus, the objects you can get with `getSelectedItem()` can now be casted to the generic type you gave in parameter to `JComboBox`. The only problem is that, when a `JComboBox` is edited, as in your case, the data is casted to a simple `String`.

What you can do in your listener method (I will use `ActionListener`) is the following :

```
class ItemAction implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            //In case the user has not modified the object
            Member member = (Member)box.getSelectedItem();
            //Just an example here
            if(member != null) {
                System.out.println(member.toString());
            }
        } catch(ClassCastException ex) {
            //In case the object has been modified
            String data = (String)box.getSelectedItem();
            //Apply first method here
        }

    }
}
```

But the problem with this method is that you end up using the first method still.

Comment: but I want that if I select an MEMBER from the memberModel that I do not have to split it. Like selectedMem = (Member) memberModel.getSeletedItem(). In this case I have to split each time the string and cast it to the member. So I don't have to split every time, because I have already the Member

Comment: Well, you could use a new thing that arrived in Java 7, which is something like `JComboBox<Member> members`, of which `getSelectedItem()`'s method could throw back a Member (I'll test that and tell you if it works)

Comment: I am using it, but the problem is that I cannot cast the string to the class "Member"..

Comment: Could you post the code containing your JComboBox and JFrame ?

Comment: I'm currently trying to have a working example ^^ I succeeded in getting objects with `JComboBox.getSelectedItem()`, I'm now trying with an editable JComboBox

Comment: Well I think if this is the only solution I accept it. :)

Comment: There might be other solutions too, but this one is the only one I can think of ^^ What you could do too is create yourself a ComboBox class derived from JComboBox and overriding the method getSelectedItem() just for working with your Member class (even though it might be an overkill) :)